# String replace when creating string literal union type in typescript

Tags: typescript, string, union-types

I have a string literal union type that looks like this:

```
type LowerCaseNames = 'youku-frame' | 'youku' | 'mini-program' | 'tiktok-frame';
```

This is only an example, since my union type is a list of more than 100 cases.

What I need to have is a new type where I would have the following "values" in type:

```
type UpperCaseNames = 'YOUKU_FRAME' | 'YOUKU' | 'MINI_PROGRAM' | 'TIKTOK_FRAME';
```

So far, I am using TypeScript's Uppercase type in order to have it upper-cased.

```
type UpperCaseNames = `${Uppercase<LowerCaseNames>}`;
```

What this returns is upper-cased union type but, I still have in them `-` instead of `_`.
Is there a way for me to create a type that I can use like this `${Replace<Uppercase<LowerCaseNames>>}` in order to replace `-` with `_`?
I am using Typescript v4.4.4.

Comment: One would think it would automatically convert `-` to `_` buuut apparently that's a limitation of the `Uppercase<T>` type

Comment: I mean, `"-".toUpperCase()` is just `"-"` so I'm not sure why you think it would be `"_"`.  (Capitalization is not the same as pushing a shift key on a keyboard)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can write a custom `Replace<T, S, D>` utility type which takes a string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `T` and produces a new version where occurrences of a source string `S` are replaced with a destination string `D`.  Here's one way to do it:

```
type Replace<T extends string, S extends string, D extends string,
  A extends string = ""> = T extends `${infer L}${S}${infer R}` ?
  Replace<R, S, D, `${A}${L}${D}`> : `${A}${T}`
```

That's a [tail-recursive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types) [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) which uses a type parameter `A` to accumulate the result.  If `T` is of the form `L`+`S`+`R` for some (possibly empty) "left part" `L` and some (possibly empty) "right part" `R`, then you want to use `L` as-is, replace `S` with `D`, and then continue doing `Replace`ments on `R`.  Otherwise, `T` doesn't contain `S` and you just want to use `T` as-is.

---

Let's try it out:

```
type LowerCaseNames = 'youku-frame' | 'youku' | 'mini-program' | 'tiktok-frame';


type UpperCaseNames = Uppercase<Replace<LowerCaseNames, "-", "_">>
// type UpperCaseNames = "YOUKU" | "YOUKU_FRAME" | "MINI_PROGRAM" | "TIKTOK_FRAME"
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMg9gdwgJwMIEMDOEBy6C2EmUAvFAOQhwCuA1tQLQBmyBE5UAPhVXdR93L4AlgDthDMMjgBzVvgEVgw2sDi1m89gG4AsACgDoSFABKEMABt0AYwgAeACpQIAD2ARRAE2KZgyMRkAGigAZRd3Tx8oPwDRYKgAEQiPb19-QJCAQRSo9LiZUigAImKAPlIDKChnN1TogAMAEgBvMSYUWABfVtCettEO5DMuhqgAfjMLazt7UxDQkMSQ5pas-ph+xNGKgC4oVfXWx1GDI3BoAFUwSDQsXDZiMmvbm3u56dsHeCQ77DxCJgQsUGMVgQB9cplAwAehhUGMVxuKAw-0eRWKAE0APKXADSl2KXBKOPxl3BADFTFkALIAUSJ3GKNIAkjgWeCAAqmbEAcWpNMZJUcLLxjmxeMpAoZQA)

Answer (score 2):

here is an example of how we can do this for a single type

```
type B = 'youku-frame';
type Replace<S extends string> = S extends `${infer A}-${infer B}`
  ? `${Uppercase<A>}_${Uppercase<B>}`
  : ${Uppercase<B>};

type C = Replace<B>;
```

References

1. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336
2. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40580#issuecomment-731124971
3. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1-beta/#template-literal-types

Comment: It should be noted that this may produce unexpected behavior for input strings that contain fewer than or more than a single `-` character.  If you pass in `"yooku"` or `"tic-tac-toe"` then you will get `unknown` and `TIC_TAC-TOE`, respectively.

Comment: Thank you @jcalz, updated to work for "yooku" and "tic-tac-toe" needs to be in your way, your answer looks like the best solution