# How to create new interface with Observable's generic types?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, typescript-generics

Say I have an interface with some Observable properties, but the type of interface is unknown. Is there a way I can automatically create a new copy of the interface but without Observable?

So here is an example:

```
interface SomeObject
{
  value1: Observable<string>;
  value2: boolean;
  value3: Observable<number>;
}
```

Is there a way I can create a new interface from that that would result in this?

```
interface SomeObjectWithoutObservable
{
  value1: string;
  value2: boolean;
  value3: number;
}
```

Maybe if there was a way to do it similar to this?

```
interface SomeObjectWithoutObservable extends RemoveObservable<SomeObject>
{}
```

Just not sure what `RemoveObservable` would look like.

Comment: what is `Observable`?

Comment: My bad, just added the tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can achieve it by this method:

```js
type RmObservable<T extends object> = {
  [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends Observable<infer R> ? R : T[key];
};

interface SomeObjectWithoutObservable extends RmObservable<SomeObject> { }
```

Demo: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMDO0Bud0A2EAPACoB8yA3gFDLJ4ECuEAXMqTQL402iSxEKAMoB7ALYQMAKwgIw1OgzjMIARnYZsUPIRKYwUUAHNyAbiWMWAJnbpRoonBAX6ViAGZNWXPiLEQJnF0aHNuXjAATwAHFAAlcS1fPTJkCAAPSBAAE0xkUXRZeUoAXkV6AG0AawhI5FBkGsjRGA4AXXZSatq2tMyIHLyknT8SUBhoZDjKAH4p5E7uyLaLLgs+cGh4JGQxSRk5MAB1YDAAC1EmMGHdIj6s3KnEnxGUvalCw8oqZB4gA

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tachibana! That works. I just wanted to add another answer to expand on yours. I forgot to mention that I always have a `$` at the end of my property names for Observables. Like this:

```
interface SomeObject
{
  value1$: Observable<string>;
  value2: boolean;
  value3$: Observable<number>;
}
```

So for this I also wanted to remove the `$` in the result. So I came up with this:

```
type Replace<
  T extends string,
  S extends string,
  D extends string,
  A extends string = ''
> = T extends `${infer L}${S}${infer R}` ? Replace<R, S, D, `${A}${L}${D}`> : `${A}${T}`;

type RmObservable<T extends object> = {
  [key in keyof T & string as `${T[key] extends Observable<any> ? Replace<key, '$', ''> : key}`]: T[key] extends Observable<infer R> ? R : T[key];
};

interface SomeObjectWithoutObservable extends RmObservable<SomeObject> { }
```

Credit to this answer for the Replace functionality: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71353081/8916441

Disclaimer: I know this is not perfect, since this would replace `$` in ANY part of the property name, not just at the end. But I don't think I need to worry about that in my project.